# How to show the name of the browse image.

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css

I searched and designed the `input type="file"` in html. When I browse a new image the name of the new image does not appear besides the button. I want to see it. Any help.

My fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/DharkRoses/X3S4a/171/

sample code:

```
<form method="POST" action="myurl"> <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
    <span>Select file</span>
       <input type="file" name="file">
    </span>
</form>
```

Comment: Look at this plugin https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload basically it directive which provide you multiple things..

Answer (score 2):

You can do this check out this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/BOQYDYsSjAW4EYOa19WN)

**Html**

```
<form method="POST" action="myurl"> <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
        <span>Select file</span>

    <input type="file" name="file" onchange="setName(this)"><span id="fileName"></span>
        </span>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
function setName(val){
     var ind = (val.value).lastIndexOf("\\");
     var substr = val.value.substring(ind+1,val.value.length);
     document.getElementById('fileName').innerHTML = substr;
    }
```